# Submission and the nuances of it

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Merrian Webster dictionary defines [Submission](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/submission) as either:

1.An act of submitting

2. Condition of being submissive.

However in the synonyms, the list is "compliance, obedience, subordination". 
It seems there is an emphasis on the second meaning. As a native speaker, do you feel so? or not?

I am wanting to use this word for the first meaning. For example after I send some info to a server, I want to say that was a "XXX info submission". Do you consider appropriate, and if not please provide options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submission is derived from the verb submit: you will probably find a wider range of meanings for the verb than to the derived noun.

The word **submit** comes from the latin parts sub + mittere, which means **under** + **send**: it meant to send something for judgement. By the 14th century, this started to take on the meaning that you refer to "compliance, obedience, subordination", which refers strongly to the **under** part- the element of judgement by some higher power.

In business (and particularly in computer systems), the emphasis is more on the **send** part.  Here is a definition from the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/submit):

> to formally send a document, plan, etc. to a person or group in authority so that they can make a decision about it.

When a web page or app sends information to a server, **submission** is exactly the right term to use. The app is sending the information, and the server has the authority to decide what to do with it.